# Reliable source of the ISO4217 table, as web service / XML file?

Tags: currency

I am looking for a reliable source of an as complete as possible ISO4217 table. Either as web service or via some REST API; preferably as XML.

I need to maintain a list of currency codes for a program of mine, and a weekly check to a reliable source would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one and only real, official source is the ISO (Int'l Standards Organization) itself - see here:

https://www.iso.org/standard/64758.html

Unfortunately, they don't typically provide online / webservice based access to their standards...