# Web Service For Currency Symbols

Tags: android, ios, json, web-services

We're developing an app for IOS and Android. We need to display certain prices on the app, and the currency used for those prices needs to be that of the country that the user is currently in. We're not interested in exchange rates, or even symbols. We just want the currency abbreviated like GDP, USD, JPY etc.. Does anyone know of a web service that will allow us to send a country name for example, and get the currency?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you need a webservice for the country codes, this question has [been asked before on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384638/reliable-source-of-the-iso4217-table-as-web-service-xml-file) but this question is a couple years old.  You might want to search programmableweb.com.  They have indexed over 8,000 webservices.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the currency code based on the available locale of the user's phone. On Android you would call something like this

```
Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getCurrencyCode();
```